# Adding NSManagedObjects to a one-to-many relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a to-many relationship, e.g. A student has many classes.

Why is it when I run the following code `_classes` does NOT have the new `Cls` object in it? Yet when I close the app and reopen it does.

And as a follow up question, How would I get the new list of classes right after adding adding a new one?

```
NSMutableSet* classes = [student mutableSetValueForKey:@"classes"];
NSManagedObject* cls = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cls" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[cls setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
[student addClassesObject:cls];

NSError* err;
[context save:&err];

NSMutableSet* _classes = [student mutableSetValueForKey:@"classes"];
```

And this is what my addClassesObject: operation looks like (auto generated by XCode)

```
- (void)addClassesObject:(Cls*)cls
{

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I assume you are trying to display this data in a tableView, are you using the line [tableView reloadData]; (maybe in the viewDidLoad:) ?  If that's not the case, can you be more specific in your question?

Comment: No table view. I just need the `NSSet` after adding a new class, but before exiting the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add objects to the set directly.  You need to use Core Data generated accessors or your own custom ones.  Look in your .h file and you should see something along the lines of

```
-(void)addClsObject:(Cls *)theObject;
```

And

```
-(void)addClsObjects:(NSSet *)set;
```

So for your particular case, you would do the following once you have your Cls object:

```
[student addClassesObject:cls];
```

Then perform you save and you should be able to retrieve the classes set.  FYI, calling this method and the relatd NSSet relatd method also sets up the reverse relationship for you.

Good luck

T

Comment: Do I have to add functionality to those operations? Because simply calling that operation does nothing.

Comment: No, assuming that those are the methods that Core Data generated for you, you should be in good shape.  they handle everything for you.  You might want to post your modified code.

Comment: Updated and posted my `addClassesObject:` operation.

Comment: You shouldn't have to implement the addClassesObject method.  It should be done dynamically for you by Core Data.  Please post your student entity's .h code.

Comment: I removed the empty `addClassesObject:` from my .m file and it works now. Thank you! I think the problem was that I added the inverse for my Cls object after I had already created both classes. Could it be that XCode thought I needed to implement the addClassesObject operation myself?

Comment: hmmm not sure.  would have to take a closer look at what you did.